# Zend Framework 1.12 favicon shortcut icon

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks, icons, shortcut, favicon

I have a problem getting the

```
<link ...>
```

tag to be added to html code in output. The problem is, that the link tag never shows up (false paths are irrelevant, I need the tag first). 
I added all variations of

```
$this->headLink()->headLink(array....);
```

that you can find by google for this topic. I think that I have a problem of understanding how and where the ZF php-code has to be added. I am really stuck with this. I added it in bootstrap, in controller, in view, in form... A `var_dump` shows that the array field is added (when no error occurs), but it has no effect for html output.

Any hints or help would be very great!

Comment: How does your output template markup (layout) look like?

Comment: yes, the layout was it! application/layouts/layout.phtml .. thanks a lot, simplyray!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This One :-

```
<?php echo'<LINK REL="SHORTCUT ICON"  href="'.$this->baseUrl("/images/Favicon.ico").'"/>' ?>
```

i am sure it will work..

Comment: doesnt work after login..  Cannot send headers; headers already sent in ....../application/Bootstrap.php

Answer (score 0):

my fail was, not to edit the application/layouts/layout.phtml

so.. the question from simplyray was perfect!